# How can I select all in Powerpoint VBA?

Tags: vba, select, powerpoint, selectall

I have been struggling for a while to find a VBA code to select all the slides and all the shapes of a presentation (for some reason this seems to be of no one's interest). I have tried to set up a range with all the slides and then select all the shapes of the range, but that does not work. I also try looping slide by slide and accumulate the selection (msoFalse), but for that you also need to activate each slide and I was unable to do that.
I think selecting all the slides and shapes at once is useful to manipulate the fonts or run a full spell check. Your help would be really appreciated!!

Comment: You can only select shapes that are on the current visible slide. To format all shapes on all slides, you need to write code that goes slide by slide and works with each shape on the slide or with the shaperange.

Answer (score 0):

Selecting objects in VBA is generally to be avoided. It's unreliable and slow. Instead, loop through every shape on every slide and perform whatever operation you need:

```
Sub DoStuffToShapes()
    Dim oSlide as Slide
    Dim oShape as Shape

    For each oSlide in ActivePresentation.Slides
        For each oShape in oSlide.Shapes
            'Do stuff to the shape
        Next oShape
    Next oSlide
End Sub
```

If you've created a font theme and applied it to the Slide Master and Layouts, it's usually easier and faster to change fonts by modifying the theme and/or master rather than using VBA. VBA isn't needed for a spellcheck either.